# SQL View for count using multiple ids and statuses

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do the following, but have no idea how to go about it in Oracle SQL.
Basically count using values of a table and create a view for it that I can access when required.

Table 1 -

```
User_ID | Status
1       | Done
2       | Not Done
1       | Done
2       | Done
```

Table 2 -

```
User_ID | Status
1       | Done
2       | Done
1       | Done
2       | Done
```

View

```
User_ID | Table1Done | Table1NotDone | Table2Done | Table2NotDone
1       | 2          | 0             | 2          | 0
2       | 1          | 1             | 2          | 0
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. GROUP BY and use case expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Comment: If I could, I would. 

I don't know how to do this, and I am not able to figure it out from online resources. 
Which is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `PIVOT` both tables and then `FULL OUTER JOIN` them:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.user_id, t2.user_id) AS user_id,
       COALESCE(t1.done, 0) AS t1done,
       COALESCE(t1.notdone, 0) AS t1notdone,
       COALESCE(t2.done, 0) AS t2done,
       COALESCE(t2.notdone, 0) AS t2notdone
FROM   table1
       PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR status IN ('Done' AS done, 'Not Done' AS notdone)) t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       table2
       PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR status IN ('Done' AS done, 'Not Done' AS notdone)) t2
       ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (User_ID, Status) AS
SELECT 1, 'Done' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Not Done' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Done' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Done' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (User_ID, Status) AS
SELECT 1, CAST('Done' AS VARCHAR2(8)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Done' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Done' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Done' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| USER_ID | T1DONE | T1NOTDONE | T2DONE | T2NOTDONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LqKGEfja)

Answer (score 0):

To get the **done** and the **undone** info, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT 
  User_ID, 
  MAX(IF(Status='Done', 1, 0)) tbl1_done,
  MIN(IF(Status='Done', 1, 0)) tbl1_notdone
FROM table1 GROUP BY User_ID
```

You can do the same for both tables and join them with the user table to get the final result

Comment: Better use CASE than this horrible IF syntax

Comment: This is not valid in Oracle. It outputs `ORA-00904: "IF": invalid identifier` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zdgnNb-w)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was trying to create a View that will show this data in my Oracle SQL DB

And after going through a couple of errors and solutions, @MT0's solution was the closest to what worked

The error that I was facing what that using the method directly was causing
`ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id)` to give `Unknown identifier` even though individually the different statements were working fine.

What I ended up doing was creating 2 separate views, and then creating a third view by doing a `full outer join` of the two views into a third.

```
create view view1 as
    select * from
    (
        SELECT t1.user_id, t1.status from table1 t1
    )
    pivot
    (
        count(*) for status in('Done' AS done, 'Not Done' AS notdone)
    );


create view view2 as
    select * from
    (
        SELECT t2.user_id, t2.status from table2 t2
    )
    pivot
    (
        count(*) for status in('Done' AS done, 'Not Done' AS notdone)
    );
```

then the third

```
create view view3 as
    select
        COALESCE(t1.user_id, t2.user_id) as user_id,
        COALESCE(t1.done, 0) as t1_done,
        COALESCE(t1.notdone, 0) as t1_not_done,
        COALESCE(t2.done, 0) as t2_done,
        COALESCE(t2.notdone, 0) as t2_not_done
    from
        table1 t1
    full outer join 
        table2 t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```